# A border around Each Data Cell In Css

Tags: css

I am new to web development and coding. I might need a little help with something I am trying to get a border around each data cell using CSS below is my code.Please help me. For some reason this is not working.

```
.table-box table td{
    background-color: #ccc
    border: 2px soild #000
}
```

Comment: Might be just typos ...you're missing the semicolon..or you aren't reaching your td elements correctly.

Comment: Semicolons are missing

Answer (score 1):

```
.table-box table td{
background-color: #ccc;
border: 2px soild #000
}
```

You have to end the statement with semicolon for the last one it is optional